# Keras error related to the fact that I only have one class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to make a CNN in keras, but I only want it to have one class and so only one probability as an output. I'm therefore using the sigmoid function to predict probability (can't use softmax with one class, which I eventually remembered). Normally I would then do 1 - probability to get the loss and use an optimizer to reduce it, because all of our answers are going to be 1. However, I'm not sure how to implement the fact that the target for all of them is 1 in keras and atm it's throwing the following error:

Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1). Label values: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

As I'm literally just using a list with 120 1s (I have 120 images), as otherwise it'll say that they don't all have labels.

My code is the following atm:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten
import glob
from PIL import Image

#!unzip not_dog4

images = []
image_data = []

for filename in glob.glob('not_dog/*.jpg'): 
  im = Image.open(filename)
  images.append(im)

for image in images:
  images2 = image.resize((28, 28))
  gs_image = images2.convert(mode='L')
  image_vector = np.array(gs_image)
  image_data.append(image_vector)

image_data = np.array(image_data)[..., None]

image_data_normalised = []

image_data = image_data.astype('float32')
image_data_normalised = image_data / 255 - 0.5

y = []

#y has to be 120 ones...?
for i in range(120):
  y.append(1)


num_filters = 1 #I guess you dictate the number of convolutions through the number of filters - 1 convolution for each filter.
filter_size = 3
pool_filter_size = 2


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, filter_size, strides=(1, 1), input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))  
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')) 
model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))  

#compile the model
model.compile('adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(image_data_normalised, y, epochs=3)
```

This is what I've got so far. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? If you only have one class your model will always output that class. If you're doing this just to get used to the software I'd suggest starting with a binary classification problem.

Comment: The desired output is simply a classification that will tell me if something is a "dog" (probability more than 0.5 as the output) or not a dog, which would have a probability less than 0.5. I understand you can do a binary classifier, but I'm not wanting to do a cats vs dogs sort of thing as I'm only interested in knowing if something is a dog or isn't, if that makes sense. I could have done a "not dog" as a second class, but I'm not sure what training data I'd give that?

Comment: In that case you already have two categories: "dog" and "not dog". Your options are to either have your code have two outputs (and go back to using softmax) or to use a different loss such as mean squared error. The first of those two options is probably better.

Comment: What would be the training data for "not dog" though? I'm not entirely sure why I'd need a different kind of loss (unless cross_entropy requires two inputs?). I would just take the the probability from 1, so I'm not entirely familiar.

Comment: I'm assuming you already have images that are dogs and aren't dogs. If you don't then you'll have an entirely different problem which is that your model won't learn what makes something a dog or not a dog, it will just always output the same thing. You are correct that if you have two outputs one will just be 1-the other, but it is required to make the loss function work. y_pred should have a length equal to the number of categories you have and you have two categories.

Comment: I could probably find not dog images (i.e. just the backgrounds of most images of dogs) but for now I'm just going to use mean squared error as a loss instead of trying to find not dog images. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: I highly suggest simply changing the last line of your model to `Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')`, I believe that's the only change you need to make to make your code run. If you want your model to work you're going to need non-dog images regardless of what you do.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing images only "not_dogs"

Try importing using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directories because it will automatically label the image classes based on folder names. Or perhaps you'd like to create a dataframe of path and class features, then use ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe.

ImageGenerator approach is very much preferred because it does not cause memory issues. Very much recommend learning this move if you are dealing with images.

Comment: "it will automatically label the image classes based on folder names". So if I labelled it as "dog", how would it then know to turn that into a 1 in order to work out the loss from my current prediction? But if I can do that, I assume the "1" it's given is somehow accepted?

Comment: Your directory should be as

class_name/images.jpg

The generator reads images.jpg and labels it as class_name.

For example:

Not dogs/images.jpg
Dogs/images.jpg

Generator will store all images respective to "Not dogs" and "Dogs" labels

Comment: What would be the training data for "not dog" though?

Comment: Images are automatically classed "not dog" which are located inside "not dog" folder. Images are automatically classed "dog" which are inside "dog" folder